# Helvetica Font is Showing Up in Italic

Tags: html, css

For some reason with a regular font tag like: ("www.hookandshell.com") I'm talking about The text links in the upper right that say "Join for FREE | Create a Listing | Sign in".  Sorry I should have been more clear.

```
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color:#029FC6;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin:0;
    }
```

It shows up as italic in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 11.  But not Firefox.  Any ideas?

Comment: `font-style:normal;` ?

Comment: Unclosed `<i>` or `<em>` tag? Or use Chrome DevTools to see where your elements are inheriting the `font-style: italic` from.

Comment: We're not able to reproduce your issue based on the snippet of code you've provided. Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Added font-style:normal as an inline style and still have the same result.  I do not see an unclosed i or em tag, and I checked every tag in the inspector and I don't see a font-style: italic anywhere.   Could it be a missing </div> tag?

Comment: For Chris' comment, you can use F12 tools.

Comment: Run your html and your css through the w3 validator.

Comment: @jackjop I did a full text search and ran it through the validator, nothing unusual.

Comment: Hey guys, the site is at www.hookandshell.com . Maybe you are smart enough do that.

Comment: @TheHawk - virtually everywhere in your CSS I see `font-style: italic` like on line 427, line 469, line 314, etc etc etc. It also shows up in all browsers, including firefox. Because they are all obeying the rules given to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This literally took me five seconds to debug. In your CSS file (site.css line 276, 314, 383, 403, 427...) you have:

`#footer .aboutLink` and `#footer .aboutLink` and `#footer .featured > p` and `#footer .featured span p` and `.headerText`

which contains:

```
font-style:italic
```

Comment: so we are smart enough I think.

Comment: I'm talking about the text in the upper right hand corner that says "Join For FREE | Create a Listing | Sign In"  There are no italic tags there.

Comment: That's virtually the only text on that page that *isn't* italicized

Comment: Google Chrome and IE 11 it is italicized!

Comment: No, it's not in either.